# Paperclip error - NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, rmagick

I'm trying to upload images to aws s3 with paperclip but I get this error

```
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/d_/k4_ps9hj5fj_3df5t210vjym0000gn/T/2611a2396a4af6938e5c5867c8bb409f20140515-7787-1u773ft.jpg'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/d_/k4_ps9hj5fj_3df5t210vjym0000gn/T/2611a2396a4af6938e5c5867c8bb409f20140515-7787-1rep3kt.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/d_/k4_ps9hj5fj_3df5t210vjym0000gn/T/2611a2396a4af6938e5c5867c8bb409f20140515-7787-1rep3kt.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/d_/k4_ps9hj5fj_3df5t210vjym0000gn/T/2611a2396a4af6938e5c5867c8bb409f20140515-7787-kfejir.jpg'
```

In my model, I set up these styles

```
 has_attached_file :photo, :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml", :path => "/:style/:id/:filename", :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/assets/profile/iama.png"
```

When I remove these styles, everything works, but I really need them.

I'm using `Rails 3.2.16` and

```
  paperclip (4.1.1)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.3)
      mime-types
```

I already installed `ImageMagick` and the `rmagick` gem

Help me please.

Comment: Are you sure it's a valid jpeg?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was that my ImageMagick didn't have JPEG delegates. I found out using `convert -list format`. So I reinstalled `ImageMagick` using MacPorts and reinstalled `rmagick` with the new Paths to ImageMagick.

Comment: In addition to installing imagemagick via MacPorts (after doing brew uninstall imagemagick), I also had to set this in my development.rb: `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/opt/local/bin'`

Answer (score 8):

I had similar issue and updating imagemagick resolved that.
You might want to try that out as well.

Comment: Updating ImageMagick resolved for me too. 

For Homebrew:
`brew upgrade imagemagick`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem on my mac.  Resolved it by installing GhostScript

```
brew install gs
```

as paperclip documentation says: http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/frames/file/README.md

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a dirty ImageMagick installation (v7.0) that I installed manually before using rpm. This one doesn't showed me all dependencies that ImageMagick needed so Paperclip crashed when it tried to use convert or identify commands.

I recommend, for Unix users to install using yum or apt-get for installing all the dependencies correctly. Also recommend to install ghostscript in case that commands identify and convert cannot be summoned from paperclip.

```
cd ImageMagick-7.0.3-0
make uninstall
yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel
```

Please follow this link for more specific details:
[How to Install ImageMagick on CentOS & RHEL](http://tecadmin.net/install-imagemagick-on-centos-rhel/)

Rubygems used:
    paperclip (5.1.0)
    cocaine (0.5.8)

Comment: This answer is very similar to another one and doesn't add any addtional information

Answer (score 1):

*Installing libmagickwand-dev seemed to sort it out.*

1. sudo apt autoremove imagemagick
2. rm /usr/bin/convert and rm /usr/bin/convert-im6
3. sudo apt-get install imagemagick
4. sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

sudo apt install ffmpeg

---

ImageMagick delegates video processing. I lost more than 5 hours to understand why such a bug NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

---

install make https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=24284

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in addition to reinstalling everything (ImageMagick, `libtool`, `ghostscript`, `jpeg`), and finally running a general `brew update && brew upgrade`, I also had to relink `freetype`:

```
brew unlink freetype && brew link freetype
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i remove styles and applicattion started works

```
has_attached_file :picture
validates_attachment_content_type :picture, content_type: /^image\/(png|gif|jpeg|jpg)/
```

Comment: Note: Removing styles means paperclip is not using imagemagick anymore

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem on Ubuntu 18 server.

You can check for the delegates installed with Imagemagick using the below command:

`convert --version`

I found some missing delegates after installs like the **JPEG/JPG or PNG**.

I purged the Imagemagick packages and then installed the required dependencies for JPEG/JPG and PNG using below command:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall libx11-dev libxext-dev zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev`

Then tried to install Imagemagick with the latest version and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

From [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1405#issuecomment-222613309)

```
OLD syntax - :styles => { :medium => "300x300>" }
New syntax - style: { :medium => "300x300>" }
```

Comment: hmm, really, new syntax is: ' styles: { medium: "300x300>" } '

Comment: this answer is wrong, by setting `style` instead of  `styles` what you are doing is setting a directive which doesn't exist on Paperclip, therefore, no styles beside the original are going to be processed. This does remove the error though, because the error is related to the style generation process, so evading this process makes the error disappear, but no styles are going to be generated.